# ssh proxycommand equivalent on server

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, rsync, scp

Lets say we have three machines `me, proxy, server`

I would like to have an ssh connection to server, so normally I would do

```
me$ ssh proxy
proxy$ ssh server
server$ # and here we are
```

ssh proxy solution that is entirely client side would be:

```
$ cat .ssh/config

Host proxy
    HostName proxy.ip

Host server
    HostName server.ip
    ProxyCommand ssh proxy -W %h:%p
```

But If I wolud want to force this proxycommand on my server, I would edit my authorized_keys file like this:

```
$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys

command="ssh user@proxy" ssh-rsa AAA...444 omg@themiddleofnowhere
```

Okay: these two solutions work the for ssh, but for commands such as `rsync` and `scp` and others, the first solution works, while the second one fails.

*Question:* how can I force the ssh proxy command on my server and still allow commands like `rsync` and `scp` to work normally?